# Uniform convergence of product of cosines

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

Let $$f_n(x)=\prod_{t=1}^{n}\cos\frac{x}{2^t}$$
It is well-known that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}=\text{sinc}(x)$$ Is the sequence $f_n$ uniformly convergent to $\text{sinc}$ over compact sets; over the entire real line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
x-\frac{x^3}{6}\le \sin x \le x, \qquad x\ge0,
$$ giving, for $n\ge1$,
$$
x-\frac{x^3}{2^{2n}}\le 2^{n}\sin\left(\frac{x}{2^{n}}\right) \le x, \qquad x\ge0,
$$ then one may combine this with the telescopic product
$$
f_n(x)=\prod_{t=1}^{n}\cos\frac{x}{2^t}=\frac{\sin x}{2^{n}\sin\frac{x}{2^{n}}}, \qquad x\ne0, \, n\ge1.
$$